# How to convert Python Multiple list to list

Tags: python, odoo

here is my python list when i debug it

```
list: [[4, 1, False], [4, 2, False], [4, 3, False], [4, 4, False], [4, 5, False]]
```

now i need to convert it to this type list

```
list: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

please advice me to implement this.

Comment: what's the logic behind?

Comment: I think he wants the [1] of every nested list

Comment: applying the method of http://xkcd.com/221/ gives us `range(1,6)`; Since you did not specify the desired logic, this might just be what you want. ;-)

Comment: thanks 4 ur comments.its needed because of my openerp get_id method :-)

Comment: You mean you want all IDs in one list. Am I right? Do you want to remove duplicate ID?

Comment: no Arya,
i already created the tempory table to post my records in daily works.now i got those records list in one2many field by passing context parameter in button.thats returns above list and i need to get below line list  :-)

Answer (score 7):

You could build the list with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [11]: seq
Out[11]: [[4, 1, False], [4, 2, False], [4, 3, False], [4, 4, False], [4, 5, False]]

In [12]: [item[1] for item in seq]
Out[12]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

or, use [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
In [13]: import operator

In [14]: map(operator.itemgetter(1), seq)
Out[14]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend this solution, this is just to show another way of doing it:

```
>>> L = [[4, 1, False], [4, 2, False], [4, 3, False], [4, 4, False], [4, 5, False]]
>>> zip(*L)[1]
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

It would however be useful if you were accessing each of the other columns as well:

```
>>> cols = zip(*L)
>>> cols[0]
(4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
>>> cols[1]
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If am I right then try this:

```
my_list_ids = [[4, 1, False], [4, 2, False], [4, 3, False], [4, 4, False], [4, 5, False]]
[my_id for list_ids in my_list_ids for my_id in list_ids if my_id]
```

Output:

```
[4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I just assumed that he might want all IDs in one list.